# Foco inicial no botão OK do JOptionPane

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

Tenho o seguinte `JOptionPane`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como podem ver o foco está na opção Cancelar maestro

Preciso que esse foco saia no OK, porém não faço a minima ideia de como fazer isso.
Meu código:

```
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JLabel label = new JLabel("Digite a senha para iniciar o auxilio:");
    JPasswordField pass = new JPasswordField(10);
    panel.add(label);
    panel.add(pass);
    String[] options = new String[]{"OK", "Cancelar maestro"};
    int option = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, panel, "Inicio de auxilio",
            JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, JOptionPane.NO_OPTION,
            null, options, options[1]);
    if (option == 0) {
        ...
     }...
```

Alguém poderia me orientar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fiz o teste aqui e bastou apenas alterar o índice de `options` que o botão OK passou a ser selecionado:

```
int option = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, panel, "Inicio de auxilio",
            JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, JOptionPane.NO_OPTION,
            null, options, options[0]);
```

Segundo a [documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showOptionDialog-java.awt.Component-java.lang.Object-java.lang.String-int-int-javax.swing.Icon-java.lang.Object:A-java.lang.Object-), este é o método que você usou, veja os parâmetros que ele recebe:

```
public static int showOptionDialog​(Component parentComponent,
                               Object message,
                               String title,
                               int optionType,
                               int messageType,
                               Icon icon,
                               Object[] options,
                               Object initialValue)
```

onde as duas útimas opções são:

> **options** - an array of objects indicating the possible choices the user can make; if the objects are components, they are rendered properly; non-String objects are rendered using their toString methods; if this parameter is null, the options are determined by the Look and Feel
>
> **initialValue** - the object that represents the default selection for the dialog; only meaningful if options is used; can be null

O último parâmetro representa o valor selecionado inicialmente ao se abrir a caixa de diálogo e se for passado `null`, não haverá nenhuma opção(no seu caso os botões) selecionado. Você estava passando a referência do segundo valor(`options[1]`), por isso o segundo botão ficava com foco. Vetores sempre começam do indice 0 e vão até o indice *"tamanhoVetor - 1"*.

Comment: e caso eu queira que o foco esteja no campo de senha?

Comment: @ViniciusLeonardo troque o *initialValue* para `null` que o foco vai para o campo de texto.